# I created CSV file using UTL_FILE in Oracle. How do I read it back?

Tags: oracle, csv, plsql, sqlplus, utl-file

I wrote a procedure to extract view contents to a file system in Oracle.
Now client want's to test the contents of the file.
How do I do it in generic way in Oracle?

Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRC_EXTRACT_VIEW (p_view_name VARCHAR2, p_timestamp VARCHAR2)
   AUTHID CURRENT_USER
IS
/* Run:
    set serveroutput on timing on
    begin PRC_EXTRACT_VIEW('V_TEST'); end;
*/
    p_query      VARCHAR2(512) :='SELECT * FROM '||p_view_name;
    p_separator  VARCHAR2(8) := '';
    p_dir_obj    VARCHAR2(126) :='TEST_DIR';
    p_filename   VARCHAR2(128) :=p_view_name||'_'||p_timestamp||'.csv'; 

  l_output utl_file.file_type;
  l_cnt         NUMBER := 0;
  l_theCursor   INTEGER DEFAULT dbms_sql.open_cursor;
  l_columnValue VARCHAR2(2000):='';

  l_status      INTEGER;  
  l_separator   VARCHAR2(10) DEFAULT '';
  c           NUMBER;
  d           NUMBER;
  col_cnt     INTEGER;
  f           BOOLEAN;
  rec_tab     DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;
  col_num    NUMBER;
  v_sql dbms_sql.varchar2a;
  v_sql_1 varchar2(32767); 
  pn varchar2(32):='PRC_EXTRACT_VIEW';
v_ErrMsg varchar2(2000);
v_Errcode varchar2(60);
v_etl_btch_id number;  
v_filename varchar2(256):=p_filename;

BEGIN

      l_output := utl_file.fopen( p_dir_obj, v_filename, 'w',32767 );
      DBMS_SQL.PARSE(l_theCursor, p_query, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
      FOR i IN 1 .. 255
      LOOP
        BEGIN
          dbms_sql.define_column( l_theCursor, i, l_columnValue, 2000 );
        EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
          IF ( SQLCODE = -1007 ) THEN
            EXIT;
          ELSE
            raise;
          END IF;
        END;
      END LOOP;
    dbms_sql.define_column( l_theCursor, 1, l_columnValue, 2000 );
      d := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(l_theCursor);
      DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS(l_theCursor, col_cnt, rec_tab);
    LOOP
      EXIT
    WHEN ( dbms_sql.fetch_rows(l_theCursor) <= 0 );
    l_separator                           := '';
      FOR i IN 1 .. col_cnt
      LOOP
        dbms_sql.column_value( l_theCursor, i, l_columnValue );
        --dbms_output.put_line(l_columnValue);    
        utl_file.put( l_output, l_separator || l_columnValue );
        l_separator := p_separator;
      END LOOP;

     utl_file.new_line( l_output );
      l_cnt := l_cnt+1;
    END LOOP;
    dbms_sql.close_cursor(l_theCursor);
    utl_file.fclose( l_output );

/*--TODO
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN 
  */
END PRC_EXTRACT_VIEW;
/
```

Client is tipsy about what went into a file.
Is there any way to read contents of dump file back in the same or new session?
(for test purposes)

Comment: This isn't creating a dump file, it's creating a delimited text file. What testing do they want to do? What do you mean by reading it in - in to PL/SQL variables/records, or as a queryable object? One option is to load it as an external table, but it isn't really clear what you want.

Comment: yes, client wants to verify that extract is valid. It's just a sanity check. external table would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate external table based on the view you used for spool.

For the same `p_view_name` you do it once and then even if `p_timestamp` changes for new extracts you can alter existing eternal table:

```
alter table ext_table location ('new_filename');
```

If  `p_view_name` changes then you have to re-run table generation script.

Solution I offer will only work if every column in a data file has fixed length across all rows.

First you have to generate a "column list view" - flattened structure containing all declared column names and lengths of the source view.

```
/* Execute:
sqlplus scott/tiger@orcl1 @gen_column_list_view_ddl.sql
*/
SET SQLBLANKLINES ON 
SET PAGESIZE 0 FEEDBACK OFF 
SET TRIMSPOOL ON LINE 32000 
SET WRAP ON
SET NEWPAGE NONE
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET SPACE 0 LONG 1000
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET HEADING OFF
set termout off

spool GENERATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE/GENERATED/v_column_list.sql
PROMPT set sqlblanklines on
select  '
create or replace view v_column_list
  as select ' from dual
union all
select ''''||column_name||''' '||column_name||', length('||column_name||') "'||column_name||'_len"'||(case cid when max_cid then '' else ',' end) len 
from 
 (select column_id cid, max(column_id)  over() max_cid,column_name 
  from all_tab_columns 
  where table_name=:source_view order by column_id) 
union all
select ' 
from  '||:source_view||' 
where rownum <2' from dual;
PROMPT /
--PROMPT exit;;
spool off
```

Because you extract without delimiter it means it's fixed length and actual data size is the same for all rows for a given column.

Second step is "column length view" generation. Because declared data length for a given column can differ from actual data length we have to create another view to fix it.

```
/* Execute:
sqlplus scott/tiger@orcl1 @gen_col_len_view_ddl.sql
*/
SET SQLBLANKLINES ON HEAD OFF 
SET PAGESIZE 0 FEEDBACK OFF 
SET TRIMSPOOL ON LINE 32000 
SET WRAP ON
SET NEWPAGE NONE
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET SPACE 0 LONG 1000
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET HEADING OFF
set termout off

spool GENERATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE/GENERATED/v_col_len.sql
PROMPT set sqlblanklines on
select  '
create or replace view v_col_len as 
  select rn1,col_name,col_len 
    from( select rownum rn1,value col_name 
            from (select *  from v_column_list 
              unpivot (  value     
                      for value_type  in (' str 
from dual
union all
select '"'||column_name||'"'||(case cid when max_cid then '' else ',' end) len 
from 
 (select column_id cid, max(column_id)  over() max_cid,column_name 
  from all_tab_columns 
  where table_name=:source_view 
  order by column_id) 
union all
select ') 
  ))),
  (select rownum rn2, value col_len 
     from ( select *  from v_column_list 
        unpivot (  value  for value_type  in (' 
from dual
union all    
select '"'||column_name||'_len"'||(case cid when max_cid then '' else ',' end) len 
from 
 (select column_id cid, max(column_id)  over() max_cid,column_name 
  from all_tab_columns 
  where table_name=:source_view 
  order by column_id)
union all
select    ') 
  ))) 
    where rn1=rn2 ' from dual;
PROMPT /
--PROMPT exit;;

spool off
```

Now that we know where one column ends and another starts we can generate external table DDL

```
/* Execute:
sqlplus scott/tiger@orcl1 @gen_external_table_ddl.sql
*/
COLUMN str format a900
set termout on
PROMPT Generating ext table DDL
set termout off
SET SQLBLANKLINES ON 
SET PAGESIZE 0 
SET TRIMSPOOL ON LINE 32000 
SET WRAP ON
SET NEWPAGE NONE
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET SPACE 0
SET LINESIZE 16000
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET HEADING OFF
set timing off
set time off
set headsep off
set termout off

spool GENERATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE/GENERATED/fixed_width_external_table.sql
PROMPT set sqlblanklines on
PROMPT set termout on
PROMPT PROMPT Creating external table  

WITH c as (select * from V_COL_LEN) 
select 'DROP TABLE '||:ext_table_name||';' str from dual
union all
select ' 
set termout off
CREATE TABLE '||:ext_table_name||'   
  ( '  
  str 
  from dual union all
select  col_name||' CHAR('||col_len||')'||(case rn1 when max_rn then '' else ',' end) str from 
(
select  col_name,col_len, rn1, max(rn1) over() max_rn
 from c)
 union all 
 select '  )
  ORGANIZATION external
  (
    TYPE oracle_loader
    DEFAULT DIRECTORY TEST_DIR
    ACCESS PARAMETERS
    (
      RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE CHARACTERSET WE8ISO8859P1
      READSIZE 1048576
      FIELDS LDRTRIM
      MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
      REJECT ROWS WITH ALL NULL FIELDS
      (' 
from dual
union all
select  col_name||' ('||(CUMTOT-col_len+1)||':'||CUMTOT||') CHAR('||col_len||')'||(case rn1 when max_rn then '' else ',' end) str from (
select col_name,col_len,
 SUM(col_len) OVER (ORDER BY rn1) CUMTOT, rn1, max(rn1) over() max_rn
 from c)
union all
select ')
    )
    location
    (
     '''||:dump_file_name||'''
   )
 )
' 
 from dual
/
PROMPT /
--PROMPT exit;;
spool off
```

To wrap it up you can create standalone script executing all 3 steps.

```
var dump_file_name varchar2(128);
BEGIN
  select 'c_'||export_date||'.dmp' into  :dump_file_name
  from  (select  
  to_char(sd,'MM')||to_char(sd,'YY')  export_date
  from (SELECT systimestamp sd FROM DUAL));
END;
/



print :dump_file_name

var ext_table_name varchar2(32);
BEGIN
select 'fixed_width_external_table'  into :ext_table_name from dual;
END;
/

print :ext_table_name


var source_view varchar2(32);
BEGIN
select 'V_TEST'  into :source_view from dual;
END;
/

print :source_view







PROMPT Generating column list view (V_COLUMN_LIST) based on source view
@GENERATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE/gen_column_list_view_ddl.sql
@GENERATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE/GENERATED/v_column_list.sql

PROMPT Generating column lengths view (V_COL_LEN) based on source view
@GENERATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE/gen_col_len_view_ddl.sql
@GENERATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE/GENERATED/v_col_len.sql

PROMPT Generating external table DDL based on V_COL_LEN
@GENERATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE/gen_external_table_ddl.sql
@GENERATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE/GENERATED/fixed_width_external_table.sql

SET PAGESIZE 99
SET ECHO on
SET FEEDBACK on
SET VERIFY OFF
SET HEADING on
set timing on
set time on
set headsep on
set termout on

var exported_cnt varchar2(32);
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select /*+PARALLEL (t,auto)*/ count(*) rows_exported from '||:ext_table_name||' t' INTO :exported_cnt;
END;
/

print :exported_cnt
```

This script will create external table DDL from existing view or heap table name in Oracle.

I originally wrote if for regular to external table conversion in Oracle.